# Django How to search if field is ForeignKey?

Tags: django

Good day SO:

So I have something like the following:

```
class Nationalities(models.Model):
      country_name = models.CharField(...)

class Profile(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(...)
      name_kana = models.CharField(...)
      name_kanji = models.CharField(...)
      nationality = models.ForeignKey(Nationality...on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What I tried:

```
    finalqs = ""
    nameqs = ""
    countryqs = ""

    if request.POST['search_name'] != '':
        nameqs = Q(name_kana__icontains=request.POST['search_name']) | .....
    if request.POST['search_country'] != '':
        countryObj = Nationalities.objects.filter(country_name__icontains=request.POST['search_country'])
        countryqs = Q(nationality__icontains=countryObj)

    if nameqs != "" :
        if finalqs != "":
            finalqs += ", " + nameqs
        else:
            finalqs = nameqs

    if countryqs != "" :
        if finalqs != "":
            finalqs += ", " + countryqs
        else:
            finalqs = countryqs


    if finalqs != "":
        hrItems = Profile.objects.filter(finalqs)

    else:
        hrItems = Profile.objects.all()
```

Right now, if I only search for names, I get the result that I want but if I include the country, it gives error message

```
Related Field got invalid lookup: contains
```

Sorry if I confuse you on my question. I am still trying to learn about django. What I want to do is do a search function. As of now, I can search by name using the contains/icontains. However on the same form, if I want to search nationality(which in my model was created by ForeignKey) it returns the said error. Maybe on how I wrote the code or something

Comment: I'm really having a tough time understanding what you want to do...
are trying to fetch only records with fk that aren't empty?

are you trying to see if the DB has the column/mapping?

are you trying to only do the search if the field is a FK?

What is the purpose?

Comment: Sorry if I confuse you on my question. I am still trying to learn about django.
What I want to do is do a search function. As of now, I can search by name using the contains/icontains. However on the same form, if I want to search nationality(which in my model was created by ForeignKey) it returns the said error. Maybe on how I wrote the code or something

Comment: Also chain it that some are None.

Comment: please add the comment to the question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just want to fetch the correct records by filtering the args from the request.
while your code *can* work with some edits, the right way to do it is via [Django Model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/)

so in your case:

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Profile
         fields = ['name_kanji', 'name_kana', 'name', 'nationality']
```

On the view it should be easy as:

```
// this validates that all the values pass (name is a string, nationality is an id that exists )
p = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=a)
//this saves the data
new_profile = p.save()
```

the only important thing otherwise that you need to keep track of is seeing that you're sending the correct values and names to the server